# how to stop mouseover function on my DIV to do not continue like a unlimited while loop?

Tags: jquery

I have a div and when click it ,it goes to fetch some information from server and put themes to itself content to show it to user it works fine but when it's work done and if user hold mouse on this div this start again to load data and this works continue like k unlimited loop how can i handle it when works done do not start to works again if user's hold mouse on it?

```
 <div id="picdiv" onmouseover="getit(this,'123')" onmouseout="killit(this)"></div>
```

my codes:

```
var xhr;

function getit(picdiv, pid) {

  $('#picdiv').html('please wait...');

 xhr= $.ajax({
    url: "/Getcontent",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: null,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (content) {
        $('#picdiv').html(content);

    },
    error: function (content) {
       //do something
    }
   });
}

  function killit() {
  xhr.abort()
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: @motevallizadeh you can use a global variable to check it is first time or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better bind your **mouseover** using **`.on('hover', function(e)`**

```
var xhr;
$('#picdiv').on('hover', function (e) {
    $(this).html('please wait...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Getcontent",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (content) {
            $(this).html(content);

        },
        error: function (content) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}, function () {
    xhr.abort();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put if condition in your code

```
    var xhr;
    var hasCompleted = false;

    function getit(picdiv, pid) {


if (!hasCompleted)
{
      $('#picdiv').html('please wait...');

     xhr= $.ajax({
        url: "/Getcontent",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (content) {
            hasCompleted = true
            $('#picdiv').html(content);

        },
        error: function (content) {
           //do something
        }
       });
    }
}

  function killit() {
  xhr.abort()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use onmousein instead of onmouseover.

```
<div id="picdiv" onmousein="getit(this,'123')" onmouseout="killit(this)"></div>
```